# Getting the size of ZipInputStream

Tags: java, zip, zipinputstream

Is there anyway to find/estimate the size of ZipInputStream before we completely read the stream?

For instance, we can get the entry's metadata with getNextEntry before we can read the userdata.

Inputstream has a method available() to return an estimate of the number of bytes that can be read from this input stream but I am not able to find a similar method for ZipInputStream.

Comment: Do you have access to the ZipFile where the stream came from?

Comment: Nope. We just have a stream coming in. I wanted to know if there was someway to get the metadata before reading the complete stream.

Answer (score 3):

ZipInputStream has method available() but it returns 0 or 1.

To get the estimated size of any type of file, you can use FileInputStream and then to read zip file use ZipInputStream.
Ex.

```
 public class ZipUtil {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ZipInputStream zis = null;

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:/catalina.zip");
        int size = fis.available();
        System.out.println("size in KB : " + size/1024);
        zis = new ZipInputStream(fis);        

        ZipEntry ze;
        while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            System.out.println(ze.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that I dont have a zip file that I can make into a FileInputStream. I only have a ZipInputStream to work with.

Comment: There is a specific warning in the Javadoc against using available() as a total size value.

Answer (score 3):

If you have just the stream, then I don't think so.

The [zip file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29) has just a sequence of entries, and then a global directory (which has a table of all files and their sizes) *at the end*. So without access to the file, you won't get to that information.

Answer (score 1):

> Inputstream has a method available() to return an estimate of the number of bytes that can be read from this input stream

*without blocking*. Not the same thing. There is a specific warning in the Javadoc about *not* treating this value as a total file size.

> but I am not able to find a similar method for ZipInputStream.

That's strange because it's there. However it returns zero, which is the best estimate it can make of how much can be read *without blocking.*

Why? Because (a) it's a stream, and (ii) it's a zipped stream. There is no way of knowing how much there is without reading it all; and there is no way of knowing how much of that can be read without blocking,